# I want to link tawk.to live chat feature to email

Tags: django, tawk.to

I am building a freelance django website for my client where he want to get orders from the visitors who visit the site, he want to chat with the visitors and communicate with them and throw them the offer, so he want to keep the chat history with the linked email, how can i do that with tawk.to live chat.

i only tried the tawk.to live chat widget, i enclosed that in a condition that if the user is logged in then to show up and now i want that when the user will again visit the site he should be able to see his chat history.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.